# How to automate by Firefox browser for functionality testing?

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, integration-testing, functional-testing

I have to automate the Firefox application to do Functional testing,

kindly help me which testing tool I can use.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important piece of selenium that you can use is [Seleinum IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), user friendly interface to record and play your tests.

Useful for automated tests of web.

Comment: Selenium IDE is a starting, it's for record and replay. It has some limitations. So Selenium WebDriver is the better to use.

Answer (score 9):

Selenium.

http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

Would probably go for selenium but worth noting there are alternatives with cross browser compatibility: [Watir](http://watir.com/) and [Sahi](http://watir.com/)

Their relative advantages and disadvantages compared to Selenium are discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi

Answer (score 0):

Consider [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) which has Selenium available as one of its backends but abstracts way all the nasty bits and generally makes it easier to write tests quickly.

Consider a quick test to submit a form pressing the Save button and setting a few parameters:

```
SubmitForm with
  %Submit% value:Save
    %Params% with
      %name% Hammy First
      %country% CA
   end
end
```